# What is the best way to find code that is blocking your main thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` in which I am placing a bunch of views as you are scrolling. it is downloading images from an api end point. The issue is that scrolling doesn't feel as smooth as it should be. I know this is because mostly something is blocking the main thread. I have searched through the whole code and commented out any UI update code, but scrolling fast is still laggy.

Any pointers on what is the best way to find which part of your code blocks the main thread?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instruments.  There's abso-freaking-lutely nothing like it.  Even apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/AnalysingCPUUsageinYourOSXApp/AnalysingCPUUsageinYourOSXApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH16-SW1) on it mentions finding high-CPU related tasks.

Personally though, I recommend the Time Profiler.  Of which, an excellent tutorial may be found [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/finding-cause-of-simple-performance.html?m=1).

Comment: can you actually find something that's blocking the main thread using instruments?

Comment: Yes, more detail please: which particular Instruments template can help me find which operation is blocking my main thread? It's either not mentioned in the linked Apple docs or not obvious.

Comment: That depends entirely on your code.  Instruments can, in some cases, find thread deadlocks, but thread blockage in general is usually a debugging task more suited to examining stack traces manually.  Besides, the number of ways to deadlock a thread are plentiful and varied, making a catch-all solution very very hard on the part of even Apple.